# Django: AttributeError 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

**I am trying to add a set of inline forms, but when I try to save the information of the forms it throws me this error**

**views.py**

**The intention is to create more orders for a particular client, for that reason I focus on the "createOrder" function to achieve it.**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from .forms import OrderForm, CustomerForm

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    orders_value = Order.objects.all()
    customer_value = Customer.objects.all()
    
    total_orders_value = orders_value.count()
    total_customers_value = customer_value.count()

    pending_value = orders_value.filter(status='Pending').count()
    delivered_value = orders_value.filter(status='Delivered').count()

    context = {'orders_key': orders_value, 'customer_key': customer_value,
    'total_orders_key':total_orders_value, 'pending_key': pending_value, 
    'delivered_key': delivered_value}

    return render (request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', context)

def products(request):
    products_value = Product.objects.all()
    return render (request, 'accounts/products.html', {'products_key': products_value})

def customer(request, pk_test):
    customer_value = Customer.objects.get(id=pk_test)
    orders_value = customer_value.order_set.all()
    orders_value_count = orders_value.count()
    context = {'customer_key':customer_value, 'orders_key': orders_value, 'orders_key_count': orders_value_count}
    return render (request, 'accounts/customer.html', context)

def createOrder(request, pk):
    OrderFormSet= inlineformset_factory(Customer, Order, fields=('product', 'status'))
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    form_set_value= OrderFormSet(instance=customer)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_set_value= OrderFormSet(request, instance=customer)
        if form_set_value.is_valid:
            form_set_value.save()
            return redirect('/')
    context = {'form_set_key':form_set_value}
    return render(request, 'accounts/order_form.html', context)
```

**order_form.html**

```
{% extends 'accounts/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form_set_key.management_form }}
    {% for form in form_set_key %}
        {{form}}
    <hr>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('products/', views.products, name="products"),
    path('customer/<int:pk_test>/', views.customer, name="customer"),

    path('create_order/<int:pk>', views.createOrder, name='create_order'),
    path('update_order/<int:pk>', views.updateOrder, name='update_order'),
    path('delete_order/<int:pk>', views.deleteOrder, name='delete_order'),
    path('create_customer/', views.createCustomer, name='create_customer'),
]
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, fields
from .models import Order, Customer

class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        # fields = ['customer', 'product']
        fields = '__all__'


class CustomerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.deletion import SET_NULL

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    data_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

class Product(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (
            ('Indoor', 'Indoor'),
            ('Out Door', 'Out Door'),
            ) 
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    prince = models.FloatField(null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    data_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
            ('Pending', 'Pending'),
            ('Out for delivery', 'Out for delivery'),
            ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
            )
    
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=SET_NULL)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=SET_NULL)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)
    data_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\le\Desktop\django-course\Django(02-09-21)\crm1\accounts\views.py", line 47, in createOrder
    form_set_value.save()
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 681, in save
    return self.save_existing_objects(commit) + self.save_new_objects(commit)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 787, in save_existing_objects
    if not self.initial_forms:
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 200, in initial_forms
    return self.forms[:self.initial_form_count()]
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 157, in forms
    for i in range(self.total_form_count())
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 130, in total_form_count
    return min(self.management_form.cleaned_data[TOTAL_FORM_COUNT], self.absolute_max)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 113, in management_form
    form.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 372, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 384, in _clean_fields
    value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 263, in value_from_datadict
    return data.get(name)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /create_order/1
Exception Value: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'
```

**I think it has to do with the way the information is managed from the template, but I'm not really sure. Can someone help me?**

Comment: Can you add the complete error traceback?

Comment: Could you please show your forms.py

Comment: I just updated the post, added the trace and forms.py @amadousow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
OrderFormSet(request, instance=customer)
```

to:

```
OrderFormSet(request.POST, instance=customer)
```

The formset requires the post data, not the request object.

Comment: I was also doing the same mistake, thank you!